# How do i parse HTML and replace specific tags using DOMDocument

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I have a text which i want to load as DOMDocument and replace specific tags.

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.in/dsfethtrw">link1</a>

There's only one thing people of the Internet love more than an absolutely epic 

<a href="https://www.google.co.in/dsfethtrfersgest">link2</a>
mistake on live television

<a href="https://www.google.co.in/ewferagre">link3</a>
```

I want to remove  tags and output should be:

```
 **link1**

        There's only one thing people of the Internet love more than an absolutely epic 

       **link2**    
mistake on live television

       **link3**
```

Code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($entity->body[$field_lang][0]['value']);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
  $node->removeAttribute('href');
}
$entity->body[$field_lang][0]['value'] = $dom->saveHTML();
```

it's giving me output like:

```
<a>link1</a> etc...
```

I how do i get rid of  tags and output only text Ex. **link1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace specific href using DOMDocument

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadHTML($entity->body[$field_lang][0]['value']);

$links = $xml->getElementsByTagName('a');

//Loop through each <a> tags and replace them by their text content
for ($i = $links->length - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
  $linkNode = $links->item($i);
  $lnkText = $linkNode->textContent;

  if ($url == $linkNode->attributes->item(0)->nodeValue) {
    $newTxtNode = $xml->createTextNode($lnkText);
    $linkNode->parentNode->replaceChild($newTxtNode, $linkNode);
  }
}
$entity->body[$field_lang][0]['value'] = $xml->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

$text = strip_tags($link);

Refer to this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php